# Return viewController orientation. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

In the application, I only have portrait orientation.
But one view has a landscape orientation.

The problem is that they are all connected by NavigationController . And when I go back from the view, the orientation from landscape to portrait does not change.

How to fix dismiss method for NavigationController?

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
  var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    var myOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return myOrientation
    }
```

**landscapeView.sift**

```
import UIKit

class SchemeView: UIViewController {

    let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        appDel.myOrientation = .landscape
        UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    }

    //does not work
    override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

        appDel.myOrientation = .portrait
        UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided everything for myself using the following method

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        appDel.myOrientation = .portrait
        UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")

    }
```